# How to remove HTTP specific headers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to, before sending a http message, remove some specific http headers using javascript / XmlHttpRequest ?

I'm using a proprietary browser, so there's no way to do it using browser specific solution.

For example, I want to remove the header 'Authorization' before send the message

```
POST /social/rpc?oauth_version=1.0& ... HTTP/1.1

Accept: text/html, image/png, image/*, */*
Accept-Language: ko
Authorization: Basic Og==
Host: test.myhost.com
```

Regards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the setRequestHeader method of the XmlHttpRequest object assuming your browser supports it, It is part of the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#setrequestheader). [It is also implemented by IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536752(VS.85).aspx).

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "");
```

Comment: I just figure out now that this is no longer necessary for me. I thought it was causing problems but not. Thanks anyway.

Comment: According the spec, this should never remove headers. It will only append values. So even if you pass null or "" it won't change the original value.

Comment: @madhairsilence - doesn't for me

Comment: Agree, this does **not** "remove" the header at all.  It _may_ void its _effect_ server-side, depending on the header and the server.  It is most likely not what you want to do, and in some cases, it can be catastrophic.

Comment: The specs offer myHeaders.delete("Content-Type") method according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/delete

Answer (score 5):

When I use jquery-file-upload, and want to remove the header in the `options` method, setting it to `null` or `''` doesn't work for me. I use this instead:

`req.setRequestHeader("Authorization");`

Comment: How using `setRequestHeader` removes the `Authorization` header for you? I don't get it. what is `req` anyway?

Comment: @vsync the XMLHttpRequest (xhr)

Answer (score 3):

Never done it, but in theory you could try:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', null);
```

There's also an unspecified `removeRequestHeader()` function in some implementations, you may want to give it a try as well.

Answer (score -1):

Adam's answer didn't work for me. However, the following did:

```js
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', ' ');
```

notice, second parameter is a string containing a space instead of empty space.
It does not remove header completely, but sets it to the empty string, which might be enough for some cases.